# Where does a stack object inside a heap allocated object gets allocated in c++?

Tags: c++

Iam having two classes `Class A` and `Class B`.

```
class A
{
  int width;
  int height;  

};

class B
{
  A obj;

};
```

i'm trying to create a pointer like below

```
B* myObj = new B();
```

Here, `myObj` gets created in the heap. where does `obj`, `width` and `height` gets created?

Comment: ``myObj`` will be created on the stack but it's address will be pointing to an address on heap

Comment: Thou shalt not use `new` in user code! Use `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` instead: `auto my_obj{ std::make_unique<B>() };`

Comment: `myObj` is **not** an object of type `B`. It is an object of type *pointer to `B`*.

Comment: C++, like other languages, [does not define a "Stack" or "Heap"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pointer to the object, called `myObj` in your program, is created on the stack.

The object itself `B()` is created on the heap. `width` and `height` are contained within the memory taken up by `B()` and are thus also on the heap.

In Ascii Art:

```
Stack --- myObj
            |
Heap      [ B -- A [ Width, Height ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject, a base class subobject, or an array element.

[`[intro.object]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2)

> The storage duration of subobjects and reference members is that of their complete object

[`[basic.stc]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#inherit-1)

The members of the `B` object pointed to by `myObj` are all contained within that `B` object, and they all have the same (dynamic) storage duration.